# Finding final size of ImageView with layout_width/layout_height set to match_parent

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I'm trying to find the "final" size of an ImageView that got rendered inside a RecyclerView, so I can adjust image in a TopCrop way using picasso.
But accessing layoutParams.height/layoutParams.width I get -1 (I assume that is the value for "match_parent"), only giving specific dp values got a concrete value, but I need that get the value according to design.
Also tried drawable.intrinsicWidth/drawable.intrinsicHeight but seems to be that those values only work if the ImageView is already drawn.
Hoy can I get those "final" values?

Layout where the ImageView is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="22dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    tools:cardBackgroundColor="@color/teal_200"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/item_superhero_search_result_name_background"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroNameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:text="Hero name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                />

        </FrameLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Code to render RecyclerView item

```
class SearchSuperHeroResultViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
private val binding = ItemSuperHeroSearchResultBinding.bind(view)

fun render(item: SearchSuperHeroesResultsItemResponse) {
    binding.tvItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroNameLabel.text = item.name

    val w = someHowGetWithOf(binding.ivItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroImage)
    val h = someHowGetheightOf(binding.ivItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroImage)

    Picasso
        .get()
        .load(item.image.url)
        .resize(w, h)
        .centerCrop(Gravity.TOP)
        .into(binding.ivItemSuperHeroSearchResultHeroImage)
}
```

}

Thanks in advance